# Automatically launch command when cd into a choosen directory

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to launch : `$ git status`
when I cd into ~/work

I thought about putting an alias that would cd me into the work directory and launch the git status, but I don't find that solution to be optimal.

Comment: Why not? It's a simple solution that lets you control the result. If you don't want an alias, then my next best off-the-cuff solution would be a pretty ugly kluge - I'd probably set a trap on debug to scan the last executed command and run `git status` if it was a cd into */work. That's automatic, but subject to bugs and a lot of tinkering.

Comment: I try to force myself to make scripts.
But I'll make an alias!

Comment: Exercise all the bash muscles! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
gitstatusinwork() {
    if [[ "$PWD" != "$MYOLDPWD" ]]; then
        MYOLDPWD="$PWD"
        if [[ "$PWD/" = ~/work/* ]]; then
            if [[ "$OLDPWD" != ~/work/* && "$INWORKDIR" == 0 ]]; then
                git status
            fi
            INWORKDIR=1
        else
            INWORKDIR=0
        fi
    fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND; gitstatusinwork"
```

This function executes `git status` as soon as your enter your `~/work` directory (or any of its subdirectory), then never displays it again, unless you get out of the `~/work` directory and re-enter it again.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that did what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
cd ~/work && git status
```

I don't think you're looking for this though.

Another option would be overwriting the default `cd` command. You could place a bash function at the end of your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file like so:

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$1"
  # detect if the current directory is a git repository
  if [ -d .git ] || git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> /dev/null > /dev/null; then
    echo ""; git status
  fi      
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

If you just want to see the `git status` when you `cd` into the root of your repo, you can just use the first part of the conditional like so:

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$1"
  # detect if the current directory is a git repository
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    echo ""; git status
  fi      
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting, I won't have to make different aliases for other repos.
I didn't even think about overwriting the default command, I'll remember that possibility next time!

Comment: I like this. I think it would drive a lot of people crazy because they hop around directories inside a repo, but I almost never do; I have aliases that scan for relevant files, and I open them with relative path so that one alias can add/commit/push from the repo root and get all my changes without having to climb in and out of subdirs.  For me, this is awesome.

Comment: @PaulHodges If you just take the first part of the conditional, it will just work on the root directory. I'll post an update.

Comment: personal edit - `cd () { [[ -n "$1" ]] && builtin cd $1 || builtin cd; [[ -d .git ]] && git status; }`